# Express js stuck on one page

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

This is my app js.When I run npm run dev the page is stuck on Report.js(page rendered is contents of report.js). When I change the page the url changes but the page remains the same(still rendering report.js). I tried clearing cache,restarting pc and restarting server but still the same.

```
const express = require('express');
const expressLayouts = require('express-ejs-layouts');

 const app = express();

 //ejs
 app.use(expressLayouts);
 app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

 app.use("/img", express.static(__dirname + '/views/jpg'));

 app.use('/static', express.static('public'));

 app.use("/js", express.static(__dirname + '/views/js/js'));

 //routes
 app.use('/', require('./routes/index'));
 app.use('/users', require('./routes/users'));
 const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
 app.listen(PORT, console.log('SERVER STARTED ' , PORT));
```

users.js

```
 const express = require('express');
 const router = express.Router();

 //loginpage
 router.get('/login', (req, res) => res.render('login'));

//registerpage
router.get('/register', (req, res) => res.render('register'));

//dashboard
router.get('/dashboard', (req, res) => res.render('dashboard'));

//report
router.get('/Report', (req, res) => res.render('layout'));

module.exports = router;
```

index.js

```
  const express = require('express');
 const router = express.Router();

 router.get('/', (req, res) => res.render('login'));

 router.get('/login', (req, res) => res.render('login'));
 module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Can you please share the content of `/routes/index`

Comment: updated with routes/index

Comment: So it seems ejs is rending only the `layout.ejs` template. Do you have a `<%-body%>` in your `layout.ejs`?

Comment: i have a <body></body> tag

Comment: Can you try adding the `<%- body % >` in `layout.ejs`.